# ImageOverlay and Rectangle Z index issue

Tags: z-index, leaflet

I have a function that adds an imageOverlay and a semitransparent Rectangle on top of that image (so as to tint the image, and draw a keyline around it).

```
activeUserImage = new L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
activeUserTile = new L.rectangle(imageBounds, {stroke: true, color: "#ffffff", opacity:1, weight: 1, fillColor: "#003572", fillOpacity: 0.7, clickable:true}).addTo(map);
```

this works great, but then I want to remove the image and rectangle with:

```
map.removeLayer(activeUserImage);
map.removeLayer(activeUserTile);
```

This seems to work well...

However when I try and add a second Image & Rectangle (using the same function) the rectangle SVG is being rendered underneath the image, so I don't see the colored overlay.

This seems to be because the  element is being left behind from the first creation, and then when the image is being added a second time it appears in front of the SVG.

Q:

1. Is this a bug? Should the SVG element not be cleared too?
2. Can I adjust z-index of the image or SVG on creation?
3. should i be containing to rectangle in a different layer to the images? How?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

OK, so the Leaflet bringToFront() method didn't work, but instead I have used a bit of JQuery to force the same approach.

```
svgObj = $('.leaflet-overlay-pane svg');
svgObj.css('z-index', 9999);
```

This works, but still feels like a hack... however if (?) there is a bug in LEaflet, then maybe this will have to do???

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The bringToFront() function alows you to bring layer to the top.

Search it in the [docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html).

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work... seems like it should, but no :(